# How to call a void method from another class

Tags: java, class, void

I would like to call the public void display() from another class but i don't know how please help me
this my program:

```
public class SignalMap
{
    private boolean[][] signal;
    private double threshold;
    private Network net;
    private int size;

    public SignalMap(Network net, double threshold, int size)
    {
        this.net = net;
        this.threshold = threshold;
        signal = new boolean[size][size];

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {           
                for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                    if(net.getSignal(i, j) >= threshold)
                    {
                        signal[i][j] = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        signal[i][j] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    public void display()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {           
                for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                    if (signal[i][j].equals(true))
                    {
                        System.out.printf("%5d ", signal[i][j]);
                    } 

                }
                System.out.println();
            }   
    }
    public double poorSignal()
    {
        int x = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {           
                for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                    if (signal[i][j] == true)
                    {
                        x = x + 1;
                    }   
                }
            }
        return 1/(size/x);  
    }
}
```

Please help  tell me if I am doing something wrong.
This is the question i have to answer : Write a method display in the `SignalMap` class which prints the array showing those areas which have poor signal (for example, display an X if the signal is poor).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it requires an introduction to OO programming. Stack Overflow is not a substitute for a good book, tutorial or teacher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create instance of SignalMap and call display.

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
         SignalMap signalMap = new SignalMap(..................);
         signalMap.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Never mind it worked, just  miss-calculation. Thanks